# Bump line-height for comments which use LH pitch accent markings

Tags: bug

[image]

Right now, the accent marking across two lines sort of merge together in comments. If we could selectively (or even not selectively) raise the line-height by an extra px or two when pitch accent markings are being used I think that would resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's generally a good idea, but maybe we should collect more data about different systems before trying to make global adjustments — on Firefox on Linux (Ubuntu) the accent marking across multiple comment lines displays fine:

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, important to note my screenshot is from iOS mobile